# Timers in angular counting incorrectly

Tags: angular, timer

I need to keep track of time for a game I made in Angular (9), for multiple players, so I have timers running for every instance of the app open. For some reason, not all the instances finish at the same time. They all start together, but some are noticeably faster than others. I thought the code I use below specifies the amount of time for an interval, but it's inconsistent.

```
  startRound() {
    this.roundIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.timeLeft--;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

over a period of about 30 seconds, some timers finish 5 seconds before others, even though they all start within 1s of each other.

I need an Angular solution for this, because the backend I am using can't run a timer. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add also the check for a date time. Like this:

```
startRound() {
    const startTime = new Date();
    this.roundIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.timeLeft--;
      if ((new Date() - startTime) / 1000) > 30 {
        clearInterval(this.roundIntervalId);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: or just simply use only date checking, not timeLeft, to prevent early finish.

Answer (score 0):

Using setInterval is not reliable in case you want to use it as a timer, because it depends on how long the code inside it executes, and that's not a constant time. I would suggest using setTimeout continuously, each timeout period should be calculated to be the time needed to the next second of the clock.

For example:

```
// Please choose a static date and make it the same on every tab
var endTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60000);

function loop() {
  var timeLeft = Math.floor((endTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
  console.log('Time left: ' + timeLeft);
  if (timeLeft <= 0) {
    console.log('Time up!');
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(() => loop(), 1000 - new Date().getMilliseconds());
}

function startRound() {
  // Wait till next second before starting
  setTimeout(() => loop(), 1000 - new Date().getMilliseconds());
}
```

If you start the timer in the middle of a second, the first second would seem to be shorter. Therefore, we might want to delay till the next second before starting the timer.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work... my timers in some tabs finish way before others

Comment: @babajaj I'm not sure how exactly you're running the timer in different tabs, but I think it's worth noting that the end time is consistent among tabs. So rather than subtracting by the second like before, I've updated the code to compare the current time to a static Date object (which should be the same for every tab)